# InvocationTargetException error - PageFactor.instantiatePage

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, page-factory

I was working around Selenium POM and it actually worked the other day. I tried tweaking my code and got this error. I don't understand what changed from the PageFactory.class as I didn't touch it. What it does is just simple log in and log out. But when it is in the log in page, it doesn't input the values.

I have these classes:

[Main Test Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9v8Bl.png)

[Vendor Page + log out method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16wtW.png)

[Login Page + log in method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb6Le.png)

[Class for WebDriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQhYR.png)

This is the error that I got:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKNEz.png)

[2nd line of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdby3.png)

[3rd line of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uKja.png)

Comment: "driver = OpenPortal.openApplication(driver..."  This line seems to be passing an uninitialized webdriver to your openApplication method.  (a null)  It's also sort of odd... circular... I'd take the driver argument out of the method.

Comment: but it worked last time, this error just showed up.

Comment: you should update your question with the text of the code/exceptions... it's a little hard to grok right now.  Assuming nothing changed since the last time it worked, maybe the IDE is getting confused about scopes/references here.